# How to get the max of $(aa^*-bb^*)^2 - [(ab^*)^2 - (a^*b)^2]^2$?

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers, parametrization

If I have two complex numbers $ a,b \in \mathbb{C} $，and $ |a|^2 + |b|^2  = 1 $，I need to get the max of
\begin{aligned}
(aa^*-bb^*)^2 - [(ab^*)^2 - (a^*b)^2]^2
\end{aligned}
In the answer book, the auther let
\begin{aligned}
a = \cos \frac{\beta}{2}
\\
b = \sin \frac{\beta}{2} e^{i\alpha}
\end{aligned}
then we have
\begin{aligned}
\cos ^2 \beta +\frac14 \sin ^4 \beta \sin ^2 2\alpha
\end{aligned}
In physics, $\beta$ is the angle with Z-ax, and $\alpha$ is the angle with X-ax.

But is this transformation is reasonably？ Why we can let $a$ with not phase factor? Does there are some math explain?

Thanks by LiZ.

Comment: Are you sure of the answer ? Because the trivial $b=0$ gives expression $=|a|^4=1>\frac 9{16}$

Comment: @zwim Thank you. It is my wrong. I overbelieve the answer so that I ignore the answer has a wrong. And I will fix the question and what my core need is the parametrization is right.

Comment: What do you mean by $a^*$? Is it supposed to mean the complex conjugate of $a$?

Comment: @Sahaj Yes. In fact, not only *, but also -, $ \dagger$ in my study, especial in quantum mechanics, it is changable. And I also very distressed about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|a|^2+|b|^2=1\iff\begin{cases}|a|=\cos(t)\\|b|=\sin(t)\end{cases}\iff\begin{cases}a=\cos(t)e^{iu}\\b=\sin(t)e^{iv}\end{cases}\quad$ with $t,u,v$ reals.

Once developed the expression can be expressed as

$f(a,b)=\Big[\ 2|a|^4|b|^4+|a|^4+|b|^4-2|a|^2|b|^2\ \Big]-\underbrace{\Big(\bar a^4b^4+a^4\bar b^4\Big)}_g$

Since $|e^{iu}|=|e^{iv}|=1$ they are of no importance for the big square bracket.

On the other hand $g(a,b) = \cos(t)^4\sin(t)^4\Big(e^{i(4v-4u)}+e^{i(4u-4v)}\Big)$

But you can notice that if you take instead $\begin{cases}a'=\cos(t)\\b'=\sin(t)e^{i(v-u)}\end{cases}$

You'll get $\quad g(a,b)=g(a',b')$

Therefore in the end, WLOG you can set $\beta=2t$ and $\alpha=v-u$ and get the announced parametrisation.

Comment: Thank you. You are very friendly.